# Using SSH to connect to a new server without storing the host keys in the $HOME/.ssh/known_host file

Tags: ssh, solaris, ssh-config

I get the following output if I run the following command:

```
-bash-3.2$ ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" 192.168.1.77
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.77' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Last login: Fri Jul  4 10:49:11 2014 from chlorine.example.com
Sun Microsystems Inc.   SunOS 5.10      Generic January 2005
-bash-3.2$
```

I would like to run this command, without 192.168.1.77 being added to the list of known hosts, but still permitting a successful login.

Is there an SSH option that allows this? I have gone through the `man` page for `ssh_config` and I've tried all the likely options such as setting `"CheckHostIP no"` with no success.

Both the local and remote systems are running Solaris 10.

If necessary, I could back up my `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` file prior to making a connection, and restore it after making the connection, but if there is an SSH option that allows me to avoid doing this, then I would prefer to use that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I see couple of more options from the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/141344/dont-add-hostkey-to-known-hosts-for-ssh).

**Option 1:**

```
-o "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null"
```

**Option 2:**

If you want this behavior because you're working with cloud servers (AWS EC2, Rackspace CloudServers etc.) or you're constantly provisioning new images in Vagrant you may want to update your SSH config instead of adding bash aliases or more options on the command line.

Consider adding something like:

```
  Host *.mydomain.com 
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  User foo
  LogLevel QUIET
```

- Use as strict as regex for host as possible to be secure.
- Setting the LogLevel to QUIET will keep the Warning which Guillaume mentioned from showing up.

Comment: Beautiful. That does what I want. This is just for one specific script. It is used for DR, and I want to be able to log into production servers that have been cloned to the DR environment. The IP addresses have been changed from the production IPs, but there is no guarantee that the same IPs will be used for the same servers for subsequent DR tests, so if I avoid adding them to the known_hosts file, then that helps avoid connection issues during subsequent DR tests. Thanks heaps.

Comment: @Warwick, you are welcome. :)